# Connecting to MySql DB in strapi

Tags: strapi

I can't seem to understand the documentation in http://strapi.io/documentation/configuration#databases

How to connect to MySqlDB? Where in databases.json do i set all my db settings like user: root, pwd: secret123, host: 192.12.2.123, etc.?

Comment: Can you add the code you have used for connection and what is the issue you faced during code execution?

Comment: Where do i put my code used for connection?  Examples would be helpful too if there's any. I'm new to strapi just trying to navigate around documentation on how to do things. I'm at loss on "where-tos" and "how-tos".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MySQL adapter for the Sails framework and Waterline ORM. Allows you to
>   use MySQL via your models to store and retrieve data. Also provides a
>   query() method for a direct interface to execute raw SQL commands.

**Install from NPM.**

## In your app:

```
$ npm install sails-mysql
```

**Sails Configuration**

Add the mysql config to the config/connections.js file. Basic options:

```
module.exports.connections = {
  mysql: {
    module    : 'sails-mysql',
    host      : 'localhost',
    port      : 3306,
    user      : 'username',
    password  : 'password',
    database  : 'MySQL Database Name'

    // OR (explicit sets take precedence) 
    module    : 'sails-mysql',
    url       : 'mysql2://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DATABASENAME'

    // Optional 
    charset   : 'utf8',
    collation : 'utf8_swedish_ci'
  }
};
```

And then change default model configuration to the config/models.js:

```
module.exports.models = {
  connection: 'mysql'
};
```

**Run tests**

You can set environment variables to override the default database config for the tests, e.g.:

```
$ WATERLINE_ADAPTER_TESTS_PASSWORD=yourpass npm test
Default settings are:

{
  host: process.env.WATERLINE_ADAPTER_TESTS_HOST || 'localhost',
  port: process.env.WATERLINE_ADAPTER_TESTS_PORT || 3306,
  user: process.env.WATERLINE_ADAPTER_TESTS_USER || 'root',
  password: process.env.WATERLINE_ADAPTER_TESTS_PASSWORD || '',
  database: process.env.WATERLINE_ADAPTER_TESTS_DATABASE || 'sails_mysql',
  pool: true,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  waitForConnections: true
}
```

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-mysql

Answer (score 10):

Solution for 2020

1. Add client:

- Strapi < 3.2.5: `yarn add sails-mysql` or `npm install sails-mysql`
- Strapi >= 3.2.5: `yarn add mysql` or `npm install mysql`

2. Change config
   `<project>/config/database.js` (for development) or `<project>/config/env/production/database.js` (for production)

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: 'default',
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: 'bookshelf',
      settings: {
        client: "mysql",
        host: env('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost'),
        port: env('DATABASE_PORT', 3306),
        database: env('DATABASE_NAME', 'default'),
        username: env('DATABASE_USERNAME', 'root'),
        password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD', ''),
      },
      options: {
        useNullAsDefault: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

3. Also may be you'll need to run `yarn build` to rebuild your CMS.

Comment: In Strapi 3.2.5 : use `yarn add mysql` instead of `yarn add sails-mysql`

Comment: or you can use `npm install mysql --save` to install mysql

Answer (score 4):

You should add a new connection like this:

```
{
  "orm": {
    "adapters": {
      "mysql": "sails-mysql"
    },
    "defaultConnection": "default",
    "connections": {
      "someMysqlServer": {
        "adapter": "mysql",
        "host": "YOUR_MYSQL_SERVER_HOSTNAME_OR_IP_ADDRESS",
        "user": "YOUR_MYSQL_USER",
        "password": "YOUR_MYSQL_PASSWORD",
        "database": "YOUR_MYSQL_DB"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The current version of Strapi is based on Waterline so if you can't find the right info in the documentation, take a look at the Waterline/Sails documentation as well.

Comment: THanks! This is what i'm looking for.